# How can I add a parameter to a submit button without using JavaScript?

Tags: grails

My form has a list of items, and each item has a delete button.  I need to submit the index of the item to be deleted, along with the other values of the form (for further editing).

With JavaScript, it looks like this:

```
<g:form method="post" mapping="defaultAction" id="${paymentInstance?.id}">
    <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${paymentInstance?.id}"/>
    <g:hiddenField name="version" value="${paymentInstance?.version}"/>
    <g:hiddenField name="deleteAdjIdx"/>
    <g:each in="${paymentInstance?.adjustments}" var="adj" status="idx">
        <g:set var="adjName" value="adjustments[${idx}]"/>
        <g:textField name="${adjName}.dollars" value="${adj.dollars}"/>
        <g:actionSubmit action="deleteAdj" value="delete" onclick="jQuery('#deleteAdjIdx').val(${idx})"/>
    </g:each>
</g:form>
```

How can I do this without JavaScript?  (Can I add a param to the URL, in addition to the posted params?  Or, some kind of multiplex in the mapping?)

The defaultAction mapping is:

```
    name defaultAction: "/$controller/$id"{     // stable URL for payments regardless of current status (editable or not)
        constraints {
            id(matches: /\d+/)      // since our action names don't start with a digit but many domain ids do
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess I need to use value="${idx}" for the actionSubmit, but can I get that index in the action and still somehow display and voice "delete" on the button?

Comment: I could generate a separate action for each index, and limit the indexes.  That seems like a kludge, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try adding params to the action name in an actionSubmit:

```
<my:actionSubmit action="deleteAdj" value="delete" params="${[deleteAdjIdx: idx]})"/>
```

I didn't find a nice way to do this, so I came up with the following hack.  If anyone knows of any improvements, I'd appreciate it.

Added to MyTagLib:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils

def actionSubmit = { attrs ->
    String action = attrs.action ?: attrs.value
    Map params = attrs.remove('params')
    if (params) {
        attrs.action = (action + WebUtils.toQueryString(params)).encodeAsURL()
    }
    out << g.actionSubmit(attrs)
}
```

I unpack the params and restore the original action name in a filter:

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils
import com.example.util.MyWebUtils
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

/**
 * Handles params packed into the MyTagLib.actionSubmit param name.
 * This Filter needs to come before GrailsWebRequestFilter.
 * <p/>
 * Updating the GrailsParameterMap after the GrailsWebRequestFilter doesn't work,
 * because the request given to DefaultUrlMappingInfo.checkDispatchAction()
 * is the immutable request saved in the GrailsWebRequest, not the wrapped request
 * that this filter passes on down the chain.
 */
public class ActionSubmitParamFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    final static QUERY_SEPARATOR = '?'
    final static QUERY_SEPARATOR_REGEX = '[?]'
    final static PARAM_SEPARATOR_REGEX = '[&]'

    @Override
    void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        def dispatchAction = request.parameterNames.find {it.startsWith(WebUtils.DISPATCH_ACTION_PARAMETER)}
        def decoded = dispatchAction?.decodeURL()
        if (decoded?.contains(QUERY_SEPARATOR)) {
            def overrides = unpackParams(decoded)
            overrides[dispatchAction] = null   // deletes from the overridden request params
            request = MyWebUtils.overrideParams((HttpServletRequest) request, overrides)
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private Map unpackParams(String decoded) {
        String action, paramsPart
        (action, paramsPart) = decoded.split(QUERY_SEPARATOR_REGEX)
        assert action.startsWith(WebUtils.DISPATCH_ACTION_PARAMETER)
        def packedParams = [:].withDefault {[]}
        packedParams[action] << ''

        for (param in paramsPart.split(PARAM_SEPARATOR_REGEX)) {
            if (param.contains('=')) {
                def (name, value) = param.split('=')
                packedParams[name.decodeURL()] << value.decodeURL()
            } else {
                packedParams[param.decodeURL()] << ''
            }
        }
        packedParams
    }
}
```

I made utility methods to override the request params and configure the filter:

```
package com.example.util

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult
import com.example.ActionSubmitParamFilter

class MyWebUtils {

    static HttpServletRequest overrideParams(HttpServletRequest original, Map<String, List<String>> overrides) {
        assert !(original instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest)   // if we get one of these, we'll need to use a special wrapper

        def params = (Map<String, String[]>) new HashMap(original.getParameterMap())
        overrides.each {k, v ->
            if (v == null) {
                params.remove(k)    // significant for parameterNames enumeration and parameterMap
            } else {
                params[k] = v as String[]
            }
        }
        params = Collections.unmodifiableMap(params)
        new HttpServletRequestWrapper(original) {

            @Override
            String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
                params[name]
            }

            @Override
            String getParameter(String name) {
                String[] values = params[name]
                values ? values[0] : (values == null ? null : '')
            }

            @Override
            Map getParameterMap() {
                params
            }

            @Override
            Enumeration getParameterNames() {
                Collections.enumeration(params.keySet())
            }
        }
    }


    // used dynamically by _Events.eventWebXmlStart
    static void prependActionSubmitParamFilter(GPathResult webXml) {

        def filters = webXml.filter
        def filterMappings = webXml.'filter-mapping'

        def firstFilter = filters[0]
        def firstFilterMapping = filterMappings[0]

        firstFilter + {
            filter {
                'filter-name'('actionSubmitParam')
                'filter-class'(ActionSubmitParamFilter.name)
            }
        }

        firstFilterMapping + {
            'filter-mapping' {
                'filter-name'('actionSubmitParam')
                'url-pattern'("/*")
                'dispatcher'("FORWARD")
                'dispatcher'("REQUEST")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I added the following to _Events.groovy to configure the filter in web.xml by extending ControllersGrailsPlugin.doWithWebDescriptor:

```
eventWebXmlStart = {

    pluginManager.getGrailsPlugin('controllers').with {
        def originalClosure = instance.doWithWebDescriptor  // extending
        instance.doWithWebDescriptor = { GPathResult webXml ->

            // static import fails after clean (before compile), so load dynamically
            def webUtils = getClass().classLoader.loadClass('com.example.util.MyWebUtils')
            webUtils.prependActionSubmitParamFilter(webXml)

            // call super after (so above filter comes before GrailsWebRequestFilter in chain)
            originalClosure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
            originalClosure.delegate = delegate
            originalClosure(webXml)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, I'm using Grails 1.3.7.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and found another solution using HTML5's "formaction" attributes.
They can be given a value that can include a controller, action, additional parameters, etc.

In General, to add a parameter to a submit button (such as a delete of a specific sub-object) on a form would looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" formaction="/<controller>/<action>/<id>?additionalParam1=...&additionalParam2=..." value="Delete" >
```

and in your example:

```
<input type="submit" formaction="/payment/deleteAdj/${adj.id}" value="delete" >
```

or

```
<input type="submit" formaction="/payment/deleteAdj?delAdjID=${adj.id}" value="delete" >
```

in the deleteAdj you would delete the adjustment stated in params.id or params.delAdjID and either save
the data within params or use the params directly to re-fill the form (e.g., when rendering create.gsp).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code creates several delete buttons and each button click reloads the page.

So why not create several forms:

```
<g:each in="${paymentInstance?.adjustments}" var="adj" status="idx">
    <g:form method="post" mapping="defaultAction" id="${paymentInstance?.id}">
        <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${paymentInstance?.id}"/>
        <g:hiddenField name="version" value="${paymentInstance?.version}"/>
        <g:hiddenField name="deleteAdjIdx" value="${idx}"/>
        <g:set var="adjName" value="adjustments[${idx}]"/>
        <g:textField name="${adjName}.dollars" value="${adj.dollars}"/>
        <g:actionSubmit action="deleteAdj" value="delete" />
    </g:form>
</g:each>
```

**Update**:

If you need one single form, you can also use normal submit buttons: give your form a fixed action and your submit buttons a value:

```
<g:form method="post" 
        controller="payment" action="myAction" 
        id="${paymentInstance?.id}">
    <g:each in="${paymentInstance?.adjustments}" var="adj" status="idx">
        <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${paymentInstance?.id}"/>
        <g:hiddenField name="version" value="${paymentInstance?.version}"/>
        <g:set var="adjName" value="adjustments[${idx}]"/>
        <g:textField name="${adjName}.dollars" value="${adj.dollars}"/>
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="${idx}"/>
    </g:each>
</g:form>
```

This should result in a form which is handled by the `payment` controller and `myAction`. In this action, you can check if `params.delete` exists. The value of this param will be the value of `${idx}`.

If you need other actions for this form, you can simply add other submit buttons in the same way and check for the existence of their params-value. You can then jump to another action in your controller (that's how those `<g:actionSubmit .../>`buttons are handled in the background.

**Update 2:**
you are absolutetly right: having the index shown on the button is ugly. So another way would be to use the code from my first update and change the button to

```
        <input type="submit" name="delete_${idx}" value="Delete me!"/>
```

In your controller, you then have to use code like this

```
def idx = null
params.each { key, value ->
  if (key.startsWith('delete_')) {
    idx = key-"delete_"
  }
}
if (idx) {
  // delete element
}
```

or if you prefere a groovier version

```
def idx = (params.find { key, value -> key.startsWith('delete_')})?.key
if (idx) {
  id -= 'delete_'
  // delete element
}
```

and even more obfuscated :-)

```
def idx = ''+(params.find { key, value -> key.startsWith('delete_')})?.key-'null'-'delete_'
if (idx) {
  // delete element
}
```

Comment: I need to use a single form.  I left out a lot, to simplify the example, but it has other fields that I need to validate and update together (e.g., payment dollars, which the sum of all the negative adjustment dollars must not exhaust).

Comment: I tried your single form idea, but the index is displayed on the buttons, and although a parameter is submitted with the name, it has no value (i.e., no index).

Comment: Oops, actually, the submit button name is not even submitted as a parameter.  The one I saw before, with no value, was the hidden input I had for JavaScript.

Comment: On second thought, I must have been looking at the wrong post parameters, because the name must be submitted as a parameter.  Nevertheless, I don't want to display the index to the user on the button.

Comment: That looks like it would work.  Thanks for your help.  I'm trying a generalized hack along those lines.  I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only **one** submit button, and replace the `g:each` with a [`radioGroup`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/radioGroup.html)

Example:

```
<g:radioGroup name="adj" labels="[put here your text]" values="[put here the indexes]">
   <p>${it.label} ${it.radio}</p>
</g:radioGroup>
```

Now `adj` will hold the value of the item to delete

Comment: This sounds like it would work, and be good for multiple deletes.  But, I'd rather not impose this modal combination of controls for a single delete.