# grails many buttons on one form

Tags: grails, button, submit

I have a form where you can select something from a selector and click and image this then fires to a controller. The problem is currently the images are submit buttons which i can send params with so i dont know which image has been clicked. my current code it as follows:

```
   <g:form controller="profile" action='postFromAlbum'>
        <g:select name="child" from="${names}" value="" noSelection="['':'All Children']"/>   <br

               <g:each in="${pictures}">

                   <g:submitButton name="submit" class="image3" type="image" src="${it.urlThumb}" alt="no Picture"></g:submitButton>

               </g:each>
        </g:form>
```

does anyone know a better way or know of a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create an analog of [actionSubmit](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html) that will support `params`, like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10941682/207791).

Another hacky way is to set an invisible text/radio field and set its value in button's `onclick`.